# Prime numbers Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have written Prolog code to (try) find prime numbers between 0 and N. I am however unable to filter out composite numbers.

Any advice would be great.

```
 check(N, 2) :-
     N mod 2 =:= 0.

 plist(N, List) :-
      X>1, 
      findall(Z, between(1, N, Z), L1),
      list(L1, 2, List).

 
 list([], _, []).

 list([H | Tail1], 2, [H | Tail2]) :-
      \+ divide(H, 2),
      list(Tail1, 2, Tail2).

 list([H | Tail1], 2, List) :-
      divide(H, 2),
      list(Tail1, 2, List).
```

Comment: What does it mean to "find prime numbers" but *not* "filter out composite numbers"?

Comment: Apologies, I am excluding even numbers with the above code, but I am unable to exclude composite values such as 15, 21 etc,. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What have you done to *try* and filter out other composite numbers?

Comment: I am currently researching that and will continue to do so.

Comment: How is checking for "divisble by 2" different from checking for divisibility by something else?  And what "something elses" do you need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start coding a predicate `is_prime(N) :- ....` without any optimization, just looping from 2 to N-1 (of course, you can stop at square root of N, but it's not so important right now...).

You can test it at the command line, `?- is_prime(13).` should give true, `?- is_prime(21).` should give false...

Then you have done:

```
plist(N, List) :-
      findall(Z, (between(1, N, Z), is_prime(Z)), List).
```

Comment: That did it @CapelliC, thank you. Once I figured out how to ID a prime number correctly I was able to use this to finish off my code. Works well now. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Can I ask, does List act as a list, and is_prime recursively called? I am trying to use both lists and recursion in my answer but I am failing to fully understand what is happening in the code. From my current understanding I am finding all of the values between 1 and N, copying them into Z, then checking whether they are prime by calling my predicate and copying the answers to List.

Comment: Actually, is_prime is not recursively called, `is_prime/1` is a filter for the generator `between/3`. And findall/3 actually does the difficult business of aggregating multiple answers to its goal, that happens to be the conjunction `(between(1, N, Z), is_prime(Z))`. Does this answer your doubt ?